# Continuity of the following integral.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convolution, integral-equations, leibniz-integral-rule

Let $f(x,y):[0,1]^2 \rightarrow R$ be a continuos function, and $F(x)$ defined as

$$F(x)= \int^{1}_{0} f(x,y)1_{(y\leq x)} dy.$$
where $1_{(y\leq x)}= 1$ if $y\leq x$ and $1_{(y\leq x)}=0$ if $y> x$ (indicator function).

Clearly, we are working under the conditions $x\in[0,1]$ and $y\in[0,1].$
Can we say that $F(x)$ is continuous?

I would be particularly interested in the case where
$f(x,y)=f_1(x-y) f_2(y)$ were $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous functions.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: Can you see that $$
F(x) - F(x_0 ) = \int_0^x {(f(x,y) - f(x_0 ,y))dy}  \pm \int_{x_0 }^x {f(x_0 ,y)dy} ?
$$

Comment: Thanks, I see that if $x< x_0$ we get $$F(x)-F(x_0)=\int_{0}^{x} f(x,y)- f(x_0,y)dy -\int_{x}^{x_0} f(x_0,y)dy  $$  and if $x> x_0 $  $$F(x)-F(x_0)=\int_{0}^{x_0} f(x,y)- f(x_0,y)dy + \int_{x_0}^{x} f(x,y)dy  .$$  Is this what you mean? but unclear for me how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is via the dominated convergence theorem. Indeed, suppose that $x_n\rightarrow x$, which yields:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }F(x_n)&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1f(x_n,y)1_{(y\leq x_n)}dy\\
&=\int_0^1\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n,y)1_{(y\leq x_n)}dy\\
&=\int_0^1 f(x,y)1_{(y\leq x)}dy\\
&=F(x),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the dominated convergence theorem application is valid because everything is bounded.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask how would you prove the continuity of $F(x)$ if we relax the assumption and ask $f(x,y)$ to be continuous only on $]0,1[\times]0,1[$ ?

Comment: @paul Isn't that precisely what your question asked? Also, are you accepting the answer?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dominated convergence theorem. Why do you say that the functions are bounded? do you think it is possible to obtain a proof using the definition of continuity? In any case, I'll accept your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The function $f(x,y)$ is continuous on a compact set. Hence, it is bounded. Also, $1_{(y\leq x)}$ is bounded above by the constant 1. Yes, you can use the definition of continuity just following the comments above.